# background-color doesn't work on a:visited but it works if i add any background color to a {background:#fff}, Is it a bug?

Tags: html, css, w3c

`background-color` doesn't work on `a:visited` but it works if i add any background color to `a {background:#fff}`, Is it a bug?

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/CMWWm/1/ **green background** on `a:visited` will not work. **But**

Now if i add `a {background:#fff}` at top then green background on `a:visited` will start to work. http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/D6vGX/1/

Comment: It works fine (FF 3.6.22). Do you understand the effect of the `:active` pseudo-selector? Can you show your real code?

Comment: Using FF 6.0.6, not working for me, strange ..

Comment: @Rob: Doesn't work with FF 7.0, but works with IE8. @Jitendra: You've just have to declare a `background-color` on the `a:link` to solve. I'm curious to know the answer...

Comment: Both linked examples work for me under OS X Safari 5.1.5 (7534.55.3)

Answer (score 4):

Check it, Firefox doing something privacy-related changes to `:visited` , Its looking strange,

> We’re limiting the CSS properties that can be used to style visited
>   links to color, background-color, border-*-color, and outline-color
>   and the color parts of the fill and stroke properties. For any other
>   parts of the style for visited links, the style for unvisited links is
>   used instead.

--from mozilla

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: yes but strange thing is it work if we add a background color to `a:link` or `a`

Answer (score 2):

hm, works if you add background-color: white to your a:link.

```
a:link {
    color: red;
    font-size: 3em;
    background-color: white;
}
```

i'm not sure if this is relly a bug or something else.

Comment: oh yes this a solution but it's strange if I have black background on body and I don't need `background:white` on `a:link`

Comment: @JitendraVyas Then use `background-color: inherit`. That will make it work too.

Comment: then is it a hack of this http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/ ;-)